# Why is this function undefined when I call it?

Tags: javascript, function, return, undefined

I have this very simple function, and it is returning undefined to me. I have a return statement, yet it still persists. Suggestions?

```
var scrabble = function (letter) {
    var newLetter = letter.toLowerCase();
    var letterSplit = newLetter.split(" ");
    var newArray = [];
    var values = [["a", 1], ["b", 3], ["c", 3], ["d", 2], ["e", 1], ["f", 4], ["g", 2], ["h", 4], ["i", 1], ["j", 8], ["k", 5], ["l", 1], ["m", 3], ["n", 1], ["o", 1],
     ["p", 3], ["q", 10], ["r", 1], ["s", 1], ["t", 1], ["u", 1], ["v", 4], ["w", 4], ["x", 8], ["y", 4], ["z", 10]];
    for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        if (values[i][0] === letterSplit[0]) {
            newArray.push(values[i][1]);
        }
    }
    return newArray;
};
```

Comment: You are always comparing against letterSplit[0] and that would be the first word of your letter.. paste your input so we can see, also tell us what would you expected response be

Comment: I really wonder why can't you use hash here. It'll make the whole things far more straight-forward.

Comment: Yes, `values` here should really be an object.

Comment: Well an input would be a letter, so they would compare. I had originally had another if statement that was a little more complicated so that it would be testing the first letter of the letterSplit array against the first letters of the whole values array. However, it was coming back undefined, so I changed the if statement to try to simplify it and see if that helped. My spec runner is just for "c" to equal 3.

Comment: why not try something like `console.log(newArray)` just before the loop, to see what it gives you? it shouldn't be undefined at that point. - as a side note `newArray` is a pretty adventurous name, considering it's just a space character away from `new Array` :P

Comment: Maybe, Stuart, but I want to do this with an array per class assignment.

Comment: Just tried console.log(newArray). Still comes back as "scrabble is undefined"

Comment: that is not your functing returning undefined, that is saying it can't find the variable `scrabble`

Comment: why is it telling you about `scrabble`? are you defining the function after you're trying to use it? function expressions don't get hoisted.

Comment: Either ways it cannot return undefined. The only problem must be the way you've called it

Comment: Patrick - ok but why? It should be able to. I just defined it.

Comment: try to see if `scrabble` is defined after your javascript loads and runs, from the console. if it's defined there, it's an ordering problem.

Comment: You have to show us where you are calling it, more than likely you are calling it where `scrabble` is not in a visible scope

Comment: Tell us what string are you passing as input and what do you actually want to do?

Comment: my simple test input would be "c" and the output should be 3.     My issue here is that this is just a function that should work. I don't know what visible scope is, and this function is sitting by itself, not dependent on other functions, or sitting amongst others. When I put it in JSTutor, it just says scrabble is undefined. I'm confused, because I've been writing functions like this all week (simple functions declaring variables first, and then writing for/if statements afterward), and they've all been fine.

Comment: I thing you've missed some part of the code to simplify it, this run runs fine, it's giving me [3] as output.

Comment: is your call to `scrabble` before or after the definition of `var scrabble` in the file? if the call is before, there's your problem.

Comment: fiddle showing it works and that order matters: http://jsfiddle.net/4539v/

Comment: Well, I'm just writing a function with a spec runner - I'm using the BDD approach, so I'm trying to make this function pass before passing in a more complicated word. I'm not CALLING this anywhere yet, I want to make sure the function is doing what it's supposed to be doing. My spec runner is still running "undefined is not a function".

Comment: When I add console.log(scrabble(c)); to the end of the code, it will log [3] to my javascript console, but my spec runner is STILL saying "undefined is not a function" and references line 3. So it's doing the right thing, it's giving the right output but both on my spec runner AND in jstutor, it comes up undefined.

Comment: by the way - I appreciate everyone's help in trying to figure it out! Not there yet :(

Comment: OHHHH!! Somehow, with all of my fiddling, it is now running in spec runner (no more undefined). I have no idea how, but it is! Thank you for your help, I need to tweak some things before it fully passes. I appreciate your time and effort!

Answer (score 0):

@Magpie, I am not sure about your requirements. However, this demo might give you some ideas to resolve your issues.

JavaScript:-

```
(function () {
    var scrabble = function (letter) {
        var newLetter = letter.toLowerCase();
        var letterSplit = newLetter.split(" ");
        var newArray = [];
        var values = [
            ["a", 1],
            ["b", 3],
            ["c", 3],
            ["d", 2],
            ["e", 1],
            ["f", 4],
            ["g", 2],
            ["h", 4],
            ["i", 1],
            ["j", 8],
            ["k", 5],
            ["l", 1],
            ["m", 3],
            ["n", 1],
            ["o", 1],
            ["p", 3],
            ["q", 10],
            ["r", 1],
            ["s", 1],
            ["t", 1],
            ["u", 1],
            ["v", 4],
            ["w", 4],
            ["x", 8],
            ["y", 4],
            ["z", 10]
        ];
        var valuesLength = values.length;
        var letterSplitLength = letterSplit.length;

        for (var valuesIndex = 0; valuesIndex < valuesLength; valuesIndex++) {
            for (var letterSplitIndex = 0; letterSplitIndex < letterSplitLength; letterSplitIndex++) {
                if (values[valuesIndex][0] === letterSplit[letterSplitIndex]) {
                    newArray.push(values[valuesIndex][1]);
                }
            }
        }

        return newArray;
    };

    var output = scrabble("H e l l o w o r l d");
    console.log(output);
    alert(output);
}());
```

Output:-

```
[2, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4]
```

JSFiddle Demo:-
http://jsfiddle.net/w3devjs/6R2X9/

Comment: we've already established that the function works, it's why it's undefined that's the question. see the comments on the OP.